# Which account is throwing the System.UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: asp.net, exception, iis-7

Is there an easy way to see which user is causing an System.UnauthorizedAccessException to be thrown?

I have a web app on domain A that runs using a specific user account from domain B (IIS 7.5 Anonymous authentication). It needs to write to a shared folder on domain B.

I have given the user account full access to the folder on domain B but I'm still getting a 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException which makes me assume that it is not actually running under this account.

Is there an easy way to see what security context the application is running under? I can output any error messages where the exception is being caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should probably need to grand permissions to `NETWORK SERVICE` user. Modify  the permissions within the folder should work.

I found  this article about [Setting ASPNET (Network Service) Permissions](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/installsettingaspnetpermissions.html), which might help you in detail.

Hope this help

P.S.

If it regarding `Application Pool Identity`, you might have look this one about [Configuring Application Pool Identity in IIS 6.0 (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/12a3d96c-65ea-4210-96ad-86a801f6a88c.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: it looks like the app was using the identity of the application pool and not the user set for anonymous authentication. If I set the application pool to use the user account it can write to the folder no problem. Do you know if you can prevent the app from using the app pool identity?